# local git code browser

Tags: git

I want to have a frontend to my local git repository like github, so I can send my peers links to diffs.

is there anything free that does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) and [cgit](http://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/about/) are web-based browsers for Git repositories. They're entirely read-only, however, without any Github features.

(Examples: [kernel.org](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git) runs cgit; [repo.or.cz](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git) runs Gitweb.)

`git instaweb` will launch gitweb on a local webserver, but it only comes bundled with "first class" git platforms. It doesn't come with msysgit. If someone finds a git instaweb bundle or plugin for windows, please edit this answer.

Comment: Grawity, could you perhaps add a bit of information about what Gitweb is? Just a single link, even to a useful source, isn't very useful to visitors because it tells us nothing about it.

Comment: And the `git instaweb` command is good for one-off sharing.

Answer (score 2):

[bananajour](https://github.com/toolmantim/bananajour) is a web application for hosting local git repositories that seems to fit the bill. It shows diffs and can be cloned/pushed/pulled to/from. It also supports bonjour discovery which makes it ideal in a local network.

It seems the project has not seen much activity in the last couple of months, though.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseGit.
It's open source, and I think it's what your looking for, but I've never used it.

Comment: TortoiseGit is a git client. Dustin is looking for a GUI for git server...

Comment: @udo: There is no such thing a a Git server as it is distrubuted. So TortoiseGit is a valid answer...

Comment: @Tom: There is - `git-daemon` for the Git protocol. (And good old `sshd` for write access.)

Comment: Yes, but that's a deamon, it's more like a service than a server.

Answer (score 0):

[gitosis](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/gitosis) and [gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) both aim to do somewhat similar things, and may provide more features than the standard [gitweb](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-GitWeb)

Comment: This is a complex solution! Far beyond the requested view-and-share, but is full-featured

Answer (score 0):

If you simply copy (or clone) your entire git repo to a web-accessible folder, you can just access it over http.

Actually, you also have to run `git update-server-info` in the repository, and you need to clone the .git folder inside the repo.

Example: `git clone http://mneme.dyndns.org/~ryan/Projects/App-gh/.git`